# How to define an empty query

Tags: scala, slick

Inside a `for-comp` I need to set up some queries that will be then run in a single shot later... say, something like:

```
val queries = for {
  _ <-  query1
  _ <-  query2
  id <- someInsertQuery
} yield id

db.run(queries.transactionally)
```

**Tip**: the queries are instances of `slick.jdbc.JdbcActionComponent#ProfileAction`

Now, I need to set up conditions on the first 2 queries. If a condition is met, the queries should run, nothing otherwise. So I thought:

```
val queries = for {
  _ <-  if (condition1) query1 else Query.empty
  _ <-  if (condition2) query2 else Query.empty
  id <- someInsertQuery
} yield id

db.run(queries.transactionally)
```

But this doesn't work:

```
value flatMap is not a member of Object
[error]  _ <- if (condition1) query1 else Query.empty
[error]       ^
```

So I bet what I am trying to do is not this way. What would be the proper way to achieve this?

Update1:
More details. The first item in the for-comp looks like this (considering Boris' idea):

```
val queries = for {
  _ <- someOption.map(someRow => SomeTableQuery += someRow).geOrElse(Query.empty.result)
}
```

`SomeTableQuery` is an instance of `slick.lifted.TableQuery[SomeClass]` and `someOption` is `Option[SomeClass]`

Comment: Can you provide the full type (including type parameters) of `query1` and `query2` in your question?

Comment: How about we go step by step and you let me know what i should provide each step of the way? Let me try with the first query.

Comment: If you have just some sequence of options, it's more simple to use `flatMap` and execute using `DBIO.seq` functions.

Comment: Hmm... interesting. Noticed that you updated your answer. Will give it a try and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some misunderstanding with for-yield construction.
In the scala, for-yield is just syntactic sugar under some combinations of `flatMap`, `map` functions.

```scala
val queries = for {
  _ <-  if (condition1) query1 else Query.empty
  _ <-  if (condition2) query2 else Query.empty
  res <- someInsertQuery
} yield res
```

for the compiler it is the same as:

```scala
query1.flatMap(_ => query2.flatMap(_ => someInsertQuery.map(res => res)))
```

if your `query1` and `query2` is some `ProfileAction`:

```scala
val query1: ProfileAction[Int, NoStream, Effect.Write] = ???
val query2: ProfileAction[Int, NoStream, Effect.Write] = ???
```

so, the type of the expression `if (condition1) query1 else Query.empty` is `Object`, because  `Query.empty` has type - `Query[Unit, Unit, Seq]` and the nearest common ancestor of `Query` and `ProfileAction` is an `Object` type, which has not `flatMap` function. To make your code compilable, you should make all branches of `if ... else` construction having the same type which has `flatMap` function, here it would be so if we call `result` on `Query.empty`:

```scala
val result1: FixedSqlAction[Any, NoStream, Effect.Write with Effect.Read] = if (condition1) query1 else Query.empty.result
val result2: FixedSqlAction[Any, NoStream, Effect.Write with Effect.Read] = if (condition2) query2 else Query.empty.result
```

Possible version of your code:

```scala
import slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend
import slick.lifted.Query
import slick.jdbc.H2Profile.api._

val db: JdbcBackend.Database = ???
val query1: ProfileAction[Int, NoStream, Effect.Write] = ???
val query2: ProfileAction[Int, NoStream, Effect.Write] = ???
val someInsertQuery: ProfileAction[Int, NoStream, Effect.Write] = ???

val condition1 = false
val condition2 = true

val queries = for {
  _ <-  if (condition1) query1 else Query.empty.result
  _ <-  if (condition2) query2 else Query.empty.result
  res <- someInsertQuery
} yield res
db.run(queries.transactionally)
```

If your query is actually options and not just queries, you can write option composition using `flatMap` for filtering empty options and use `seq` for sequential execution of result queries sequence. Example, using table in [slick documentation](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.2.0/queries.html):

```scala
import slick.jdbc.H2Profile.api._

case class Coffees(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Double)](tag, "COFFEES") {
  def name = column[String]("COF_NAME")
  def price = column[Double]("PRICE")
  def * = (name, price)
}
val coffees: TableQuery[Coffees] = TableQuery[Coffees]

val maybeQuery1 = Option(("Colombian", 7.99))
val maybeQuery2 = Option(("Another name", 14.59))
val maybeQuery3 = Option(("Name", 4.39))
val queries = Seq(maybeQuery1, maybeQuery2, maybeQuery3).flatMap(_.map(someRow => coffees += someRow))

val db: Database = ???
db.run(DBIO.seq(queries:_*).transactionally)
```

Comment: Yeah, I endup up figuring out that it is a problem with whatever-API-I-am-using is returning... probably not a Query subclass and that's why it goes all the way up to `Object`.

Comment: what version of slick are you using?

Comment: Ok.... I see what is going on with your example. You are using `Query` straight. In my case, `query1` and `query2` are instances of `slick.jdbc.JdbcActionComponent#ProfileAction`

Comment: It compiles... but it fails during execution with a `ClassCastException`: `slick.jdbc.JdbcActionComponent$QueryActionExtensionMethodsImpl$$anon$3 cannot be cast to slick.sql.FixedSqlStreamingAction` (when calling `resut()` in `Query.empty.result()`)

Comment: because my code is just an example, you should think about the suitable type for the general type of query and your empty query. It is hard to give you an answer without all code (type parameters, imports, and so on).

Comment: Can you elaborate on this specific point in your answer so that I can see what I should check (I'm not the most knowledgable person about slick).

Comment: By the way, thanks for the effort so far.

Comment: Use of `Seq` then `DBIO.seq`/`DBIO.sequence` does checkout. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have been able to solve it til now is by getting the condition inside a `filter`. Roughly:

```
val queries = for {
  _ <-  query1.filter(condition1)
  _ <-  query2.filter(condition2)
  id <- someInsertQuery
} yield id

db.run(queries.transactionally)
```

Let me know if you have other ideas.

Comment: I think the semantic of the expression `query.filter(condition)` is not the same as `if (condition) query else Query.empty`